# Full text population progress - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Does anyone knows how to query a full text catalog population to see its progress in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sys.dm_fts_index_population`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186897.aspx)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_population
```

Comment: That does not show me the progress or how long it will takes to finish pupulating.

Comment: @Rafael: it only shows active populations. Are you having one currently?

Comment: Yeah, I have. But i need to know how long (approximately) it will takes to finish building the catalog.